Lag time between FDA approval and FDA API label release
I am looking at the openFDA dataset, and found that only now were we seeing recently approved drugs (6/20) added to our database (e.g., Ojemda). Is there a bug in our system or is the average lag time between when a drug is approved and the label released is 2 months? Thanks so much!

Unfortunately, the openFDA team does not have information about the "lag time" between approval and release events. We receive drug labels from an internal communication channel and process them the same day, but unfortunately we don't have insight into the process that supplies labels to us. You could try reaching out to the FDA directly with this question.
Ojemda (SPL ID c117b4d5-b7fa-4a0a-bcb6-eed8216c7f86) was supplied to us on 5/31/2024, in case this helps.
